# Resources on on-line machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, references

I am wondering if there are any books/articles/tutorials about "on-line machine learning"?

For example, this website has nice lecture notes (from lec16) on some of the aspects:
[https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~jabernet/eecs598course/fall2015/web/](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ejabernet/eecs598course/fall2015/web/)

or this book:

[https://ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/AGT/Prediction_Learning_and_Games.pdf](https://ii.uni.wroc.pl/%7Elukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/AGT/Prediction_Learning_and_Games.pdf)

I can't seem to find much resources on this. I'm trying to understand the basics, not read research papers. If anyone can share resources that would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On-line learning algorithms** trains new data as it arrives.
It is often referred to as **incremental learning** or **continuous learning** as it trains continuous stream of data incrementally

As requested some resources in the form of books, tutorial, lecture notes, YouTube links, pdf documents along with available packages that support online learning algorithms are mentioned below

**BOOKS**

- [Online Algorithms: The State of the Art](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0029561)
- [Online learning and Online convex optimization](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/papers/OLsurvey.pdf)
- [Regret Analysis of Stochastic and Nonstochastic Multi-armed Bandit Problems](http://sbubeck.com/SurveyBCB12.pdf)
- [Convex Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity](http://sbubeck.com/Bubeck15.pdf)
- [Introduction to  Online Convex Optimization](https://sites.google.com/view/intro-oco/)
- [Introduction to Online Optimization](http://sbubeck.com/BubeckLectureNotes.pdf)

**TUTORIAL**

- [An Introduction To Online Machine Learning](https://dziganto.github.io/data%20science/online%20learning/python/scikit-learn/An-Introduction-To-Online-Machine-Learning/)
- [A Simple Introduction to Online Machine Learning](https://www.iunera.com/kraken/fabric/simple-introduction-to-online-learning-in-machine-learning/)
- [Beginner’s Guide to Online Machine Learning](https://analyticsindiamag.com/beginners-guide-to-online-machine-learning/)
- [what is online machine learning](https://medium.com/value-stream-design/online-machine-learning-515556ff72c5)
- [Online Machine Learning Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)
- [Online learning simplified](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/01/introduction-online-machine-learning-simplified-2/)
- [what is online machine learning](https://medium.com/value-stream-design/online-machine-learning-515556ff72c5)

**LECTURE**

- [Online Methods in Machine Learning
  Theory and Applications](https://www.mit.edu/%7Erakhlin/6.883/)
- [Coursera lecture on online machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/online-learning-ABO2q)

**YOU TUBE**

- [Introduction to online machine learning algorithms](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=O3gd6elZOlA)
- [what is Online Machine learning](https://youtu.be/V4VEJ6O5ycE)
- [Online Machine learning with creme](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=P3M6dt7bY9U)

**PDF**

- [Online Learning:
  Theory, Algorithms, and Applications](https://home.ttic.edu/%7Eshai/papers/ShalevThesis07.pdf)
- [Online Learning: A Comprehensive Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02871)
- [14 chapter on-line learning algorithms in machine learning](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eavrim/Papers/survey.pdf)
- [Utilisation of on-line machine learning for SCADA system alarms forecasting](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6661782)
- [Online Machine Learning Algorithms Review and Comparison in Healthcare](https://trace.tennessee.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=6803&context=utk_gradthes)

**ONLINE LEARNING ALGORITHMS**

- [Vowpal Wabbit](https://vowpalwabbit.org) : provides support for reinforcement learning and supervised learning
- [Creme](https://github.com/MaxHalford/creme)
- [Scikit-multiflow](https://github.com/scikit-multiflow/scikit-multiflow)
- [River](https://github.com/online-ml/river) - online machine learning python package that combines python packages creme and scikit-multiflow
- [LIBOL: A Library for Online Learning Algorithms](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/hoi14a/hoi14a.pdf)
- Quasi-additive Online Classification Algorithms
- [Game Theory, on-line prediction and boosting](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eninamf/LGO10/wm-minimax.pdf) Freund and Schapire relates boosting algorithms to online learning(Adaboost)